# Sharepoint 2010 List Settings

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I am Using a List in which i created Approval Required Column as Choice(Drop Down) with values Yes or No. Also i have a People Picker Column. The objective is the people picker must be disabled or hide if the value No is being selected and people picker must be available when the value Yes is selected from the choice(Drop Down). Any ideas?

Thanks,

Prasath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try editing the display form of the list in Sharepoint Designer, and add a jquery script to attach to the dropdown changed event to handle the diplay/hide logic.